# No target application path specified via test configuration TVOS

Tags: swift, tvos, xcode-ui-testing

I have a UI Test target for TVOS, but when I try and run the default test (Which does nothing) I get the following crash:

I can confirm I have a UI Test Target, it seems that all of the (nulls) shouldn't be there. Any Ideas?

```
    2016-07-15 11:34:20.294 XCTRunner[520:131793] *** Assertion failure in -[XCUIApplication init], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/XCTest_Ponderosa/XCTest-10112/XCTestFramework/UI Testing/XCUIApplication.m:72
<unknown>:0: error: -[MyAppUITests.MyAppUITests testExample] : failed: caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "No target application path specified via test configuration: <XCTestConfiguration: 0x14561c890>
                      testBundleURL:file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/1FC15F64-7D6B-4A62-962C-C79B797DDC33/MyAppUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/MyAppUITests.xctest/
             testBundleRelativePath:(null)
                  productModuleName:(null)
                        testsToSkip:(null)
                         testsToRun:(null)
                 reportResultsToIDE:no
                  sessionIdentifier:<__NSConcreteUUID 0x145520b30> 3373A932-0ACE-47E4-9FF8-DB9267E370EB
         pathToXcodeReportingSocket:(null)
          disablePerformanceMetrics:no
    treatMissingBaselinesAsFailures:no
                    baselineFileURL:(null)
           baselineFileRelativePath:(null)
              targetApplicationPath:(null)
          targetApplicationBundleID:(null)
                   reportActivities:no
           testsMustRunOnMainThread:no
             initializeForUITesting:no
"
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018682a0b4 <redacted> + 148
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000185e8ff80 objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000186829f6c <redacted> + 0
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001871a4294 <redacted> + 112
    4   XCTest                              0x00000001000d90e0 -[XCUIApplication init] + 200
    5   MyAppUITests                      0x000000010043fd90 _TTOFCSo15XCUIApplicationcfT_S_ + 24
    6   MyAppUITests                      0x000000010043fd18 _TFCSo15XCUIApplicationCfT_S_ + 80
    7   MyAppUITests                      0x000000010043f758 _TFC14MyAppUITests14MyAppUITests5setUpfT_T_ + 144
    8   MyAppUITests                      0x000000010043f80c _TToFC14MyAppUITests14MyAppUITests5setUpfT_T_ + 40
    9   XCTest                              0x00000001000ba958 __24-[XCTestCase invokeTest]_block_invoke_2 + 120
    10  XCTest                              0x00000001000ebb7c -[XCTestContext performInScope:] + 208
    11  XCTest                              0x00000001000ba8cc -[XCTestCase invokeTest] + 164
    12  XCTest                              0x00000001000baeb8 -[XCTestCase performTest:] + 460
    13  XCTest                              0x00000001000b8028 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 384
    14  XCTest                              0x00000001000b8028 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 384
    15  XCTest                              0x00000001000b8028 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 384
    16  XCTest                              0x00000001000c5b08 -[XCTestObservationCenter _observeTestExecutionForBlock:] + 596
    17  XCTest                              0x00000001000ed078 _XCTestMain + 1056
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001867e028c <redacted> + 20
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001867dfbc4 <redacted> + 308
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001867ddb28 <redacted> + 708
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000186708c60 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000187fdc088 GSEventRunModal + 180
    23  UIKit                               0x000000018b905fe4 UIApplicationMain + 204
    24  XCTRunner                           0x000000010007e4fc XCTRunner + 25852
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001862a6974 <redacted> + 4
)
```

The only *kinda* fix I have at the moment is to delete all provisioning profiles off of the device, reboot it and then it works for maybe 5-6 runs, then I get the error message again.

Comment: Are you using Cocoapods and `use_frameworks!`?

Comment: No, I am not using Cocoapods.

Comment: The same  thing is happening to me. Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: Sorry, I gave up :-(